# Searchform in extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase

I tried to add a simple searchform to my extbase extension which doesn't work like supposed. I want to pass the input (keyword) as an argument to my searchAction.

//added to **list.html**

```
<f:form action="search" arguments="{keyword}">
  <f:form.textfield name="keyword" value="Suchbegriff">
  <f:form.submit value="Suchen" />
</f:form>
```

//added to **ItemController.php**

```
/**
 * action search
 *
 * @param \string $keyword
 * @return void
 */
public function searchAction($keyword='') {

    $items = $this->itemRepository->findKeyword($keyword);
    $this->view->assign('items', $items);
}
```

**How do i pass the input from the textfield `keyword` to my ItemControllers `searchAction()`???**

Comment: You can leave out the `arguments="{keyword}"`-part. Except for that, I don't see any problems with your code.

Comment: Are you sure that it really doesn't pass the argument to your `searchAction()`? Use the `devlog` Extension and `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::devLog($keyword, 'your_extension_key');` in your action to check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all arguments from your view by using following method in your controller Action.

```
$this->request->getArguments();
```

By using this method you can check whether your arguments is passed or not.
also you can check like this:

```
if($this->request->hasArgument('Search')) { }
```

If your field is keyword then you can find like this:

```
if($this->request->hasArgument('Search')) { 
    $items = $this->itemRepository->findKeyword($this->request->getArgument('Search'));
}
$this->view->assign('searchItems', $items);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wonder that you don't get an exception. Arguments is type of array.
Your form have to look like this.

```
<f:form action="search" arguments="{keyword:keyword}">
  <f:form.textfield name="keyword" value="Suchbegriff">
  <f:form.submit value="Suchen" />
</f:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your html form should bel like this

```
<f:form action="search" name="query">
  <f:form.textfield property="keyword" value="">
  <f:form.submit value="Suchen" />
</f:form>
```

in your controller should be like this

```
/**
 * action search
 *
 * @param \string $keyword
 * @return void
 */
public function searchAction($keyword='') {

    if ($this->request->hasArgument('query')) {
        $search = $this->request->getArgument('query');
        $items = $this->itemRepository->findKeyword($keyword);
    }
    $this->view->assign('items', $items);
}
```

in your repository should be like this

```
/**
 * Gets events following by request
 *
 *
 * @param string $request Keyword
 * @return object
 */

public function findKeyword($request = NULL){
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    if($request['string']) {
        $result =  $query->matching($query->like('name', '%'.$request['string'].'%'))->execute();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Hope it will help!